# How to exclude the current user from a saved list

Tags: php, wordpress, exclude-constraint

I'm trying to exclude the current user from a saved list. My code is including every user that has saved a user but I don't want the current user in the list. How does one exclude the current user? Here is my code.

```
<?php
$sql              = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type IN ('" . $directory_url_1 . "','" . $directory_url_2 . "' ) and post_author='" . $current_user->ID . "' and post_status IN ('publish','pending','draft' )  ";
$authpr_post      = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
$total_post       = count( $authpr_post );
$iv_redirect_user = get_option( '_iv_directories_profile_public_page' );
$reg_page_user    = '';
if ( $iv_redirect_user != 'defult' ) {
    $reg_page_user = get_permalink( $iv_redirect_user );
}
if ( $total_post > 0 ) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $authpr_post as $row ) {        //echo '<br/>ID...'.$row->ID;
        $user_list      = get_post_meta( $row->ID, '_favorites', TRUE );
        $user_list_arr2 = [];
        $user_list_arr  = array_filter( explode( ",", $user_list ), 'strlen' );
        $i              = 0;
        foreach ( $user_list_arr as $arr ) {
            if ( trim( $arr ) != '' ) {
                $user_list_arr2[ $i ] = $arr;
                $i ++;
            }
        }
        if ( sizeof( $user_list_arr2 ) > 0 ) {

            $args_users = ['include' => $user_list_arr2,];
            // The User Query
            $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args_users );

            if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
                foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
                    //print_r( $user );                                                 
                    ?>
```

I tried adding this string but it did not work. Oh, I'm also very new at this and may have not added it properly.

```
$filtered_user = user.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
$print("ALL USERS:" + str(filtered_user))

args = {
  'user': user,
  $'filtered_user':
```

Comment: The attempt you have written doesn't look like PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using array_filter, you can extend the filter and remove some code, excluding also the current user:

```
if ( $total_post > 0 ) {
    $i = 0;  // is this necessary?? 
    foreach ( $authpr_post as $row ) {        //echo '<br/>ID...'.$row->ID;
        $user_list      = get_post_meta( $row->ID, '_favorites', TRUE );
        // REMOVE $user_list_arr2 = [];
        // SUBSTITUTE $user_list_arr  = array_filter( explode( ",", $user_list ), 'strlen' );
        $user_list_arr = array_filter(explode(',', $user_list), fn ($v) => ($tv = trim($v)) && $tv != $current_user->ID);
        
        /*  REMOVE
        $i              = 0;
        foreach ( $user_list_arr as $arr ) {
            if ( trim( $arr ) != '' ) {
                $user_list_arr2[ $i ] = $arr;
                $i ++;
            }
        }
        */
        
        // Now you must use $user_list_arr instead of $user_list_arr2
        
        if ( sizeof($user_list_arr) > 0 ) {  // you could use count($user_list_arr) as you did for $total_post

            $args_users = ['include' => $user_list_arr];
            // The User Query
            $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args_users );

            if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
                foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
                    //print_r( $user );
```

Answer (score 0):

- I have never been a WordPress developer.
- There are iterated trips to the database -- these are not best practice; table JOINing should be implemented instead.
- There are comma-separated values in database tables -- this is not best practice; the database should be normalized.
- My snippet below is not tested.

---

1. Use a prepared statement to fetch all qualifying posts.
2. Iterate those results and build the `include` array using `preg_split()`.
3. Build the regex pattern to destroy potential spaces next to delimiting commas and also treat the current user's id as a delimiter so that it is not included in the returned array.
4. Use `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY()` to filter out any empty values.

Code:

```
$current_user_posts = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        <<<SQL
            SELECT *
            FROM $wpdb->posts
            WHERE post_author=%d
                  AND post_type IN (%s,%s)
                  AND post_status IN ('publish','pending','draft')
        SQL,
        [$current_user->ID, $directory_url_1, $directory_url_2]
    )
);

foreach ($current_user_posts as $post) {
    $args_users = [
        'include' => preg_split(
            "/ *, *|\b{$current_user->ID}\b/",
            trim(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_favorites', TRUE)),
            0,
            PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
        )
    ];
    foreach ((new WP_User_Query($args_users))->get_results() as $user) {
        // do whatever you need to do
    }
}
```